# Catching event with stopped propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to somehow catch event, if it's propagation was stopped?

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Maybe there are some kind of global handler? Like:

```
Event.registerHandler('click', function(e) {
  alert('thanks');
});
```

There should be no additional code for regular handlers.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean doing something with the event *beyond* the point at which it has been stopped, then no.

You can, however make the same function that stops the event propagation do something else - even dispatch another click event if that's what you want.